# Why does web3.js reject a valid RSK smart contract address?

Tags: web3js, checksum, rsk

I'm trying to interact with smart contracts on the RSK Mainnet, and I'm getting this error...

```
Provided address "0xAb2d290b7a600f5eA8d5B933f6F15c867Fd7e60e" is invalid,
the capitalization checksum test failed, 
or its an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted.
```

The address is obtained from RSK Explorer itself, so I'm not sure why web3.js has this error.

Comment: [TylerH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh)  Why you edit my question that I did a long time ago and I got I excellent response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [RSKIP-60](https://github.com/rsksmart/RSKIPs/blob/master/IPs/RSKIP60.md), RSK network has its own checksum validation following [EIP1191](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1191.md).

However, some tools and libraries still don't support EIP-1191.

Most Ethereum tools and libraries support EIP-155 only.
web3.js is one of them, and it checks the checksum expecting an EIP-155 checksum.

**Workarounds**

(1) Convert the smart contract address to an all-lowercase string:

```js
return new web3.eth.Contract(coinBackAbi, tokenObj.address.toString().toLowerCase());
```

Note that both EIP-155 and EIP-1191 define that all-lowercase addresses are to be treated as "skip checksum".

(2) Another approach is to use [`@rsksmart/rsk-utils`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rsksmart/rsk-utils),
using this to convert the address to use the appropriate checksum:

```js
// Ethereum --> use this for web3.js
toChecksumAddress ("0xAb2d290b7a600f5eA8d5B933f6F15c867Fd7e60e", null)
// RSK Mainnet
toChecksumAddress ("0xAb2d290b7a600f5eA8d5B933f6F15c867Fd7e60e", 30)
```